# Classname besides a variable in PHP

Tags: php, function, laravel, class

I dont understand this in PHP, there is a classname and a variable right besides it inside a functions parentheses, sometimes there can be multiple separated by a comma, and then all the class public methods are available for use by using the variable associated with the class.

```
        Schema::create('news_feeds', /*Here*/ function (Blueprint $table)/*To Here*/ {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('content');
            $table->string('date');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

This piece of code is from a laravel script,

Im trying to search for how it work but I dont know what its called, so what is this method of doing things called in PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: Those are the function arguments, the Classes are the types that the variable names represent instances of.

Comment: The variable $somevar needs to be of the type SomeClass. If it's not an Exception is thrown

Comment: Exception for php7, fatal error in previous versions @jrenk

Comment: This type of function is called Anonymous Function: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Schema::create('news_feeds', function(Blueprint $table) {
//^       ^      ^             ^        ^         ^
//|       |      |             |        |         |
//|       |      |             |        |         -- 1st function param.
//|       |      |             |        -- Typehint for 1st function param.
//|       |      |             -- Second method argument
//|       |      -- First method argument
//|       --Method Name
//--Class Name
  });
```

You need to understand that since you are on a framework like Laravel, some behaviors don't belong to PHP itself.

The piece of code that you don't understand, is called `anonymous function`, and it's often used as a `callback`.

On the backstage, Laravel is doing this:

- Okay, he called `Schema::create` to create a table called `news_feeds`
- Lets create an `Blueprint` object
- I'll send this  object to user modify. (Laravel calls here your callback with the Blueprint as parameter)
- Once the `callback` was executed, the Blueprint will be "executed", here the table is really being created on database.

If you really want to know how exactly this is being made, go to the class `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder` and look for the method `create`.

To make you life easier, using an IDE like PHPStorm, you can follow methods, classes and variables in a easy way by using `ctrl+b` shortcut...

```
public function create($table, Closure $callback)
{
    $blueprint = $this->createBlueprint($table);

    $blueprint->create();

    $callback($blueprint);

    $this->build($blueprint);
}
```

Look at create method the steps I told you.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what i needed to see to continue thank you very much